# I want to create a new dataframe summarising all data between 6am-7am only, everyday over the course of 7 months in Python pandas

Tags: python

This is what I have done but this is not how I want it:

```
sunrise = dataset[(dataset["date_time"].between("2019-03-31 06:00:00", "2019-03-31 07:00:00"))]

sunrise_accidents = len(sunrise)
print("Sunrise accidents: ", sunrise_accidents)

total_sunrise_accidents = sunrise_accidents * 211
print("Total accidents that occurred at sunrise during daylight savings: ",total_sunrise_accidents)
```

But I'd rather want this all to be in the new data frame; all data between 6am - 7am only, everyday from mar 31st to oct 27th same year

#211 is the number of days between the march 31st and oct 27th

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you convert the 'date_time' Series to a pandas DatetimeIndex: it has very useful attributes `hour`, `minute`...

Then, you can get a mask with only the specified hours. In this instance, I select all samples with hour `6`, so all samples that occurred within the ours 6:00 to 6:59. The mask is a boolean array, its sum is the number of samples that occurred in the desired hour.

Then, you can get all the samples from the original data-set that occurred in the desired hours, using the `.loc` method.

```py
dates = pd.Index(pd.to_datetime(dataset['date_time']))

hour_of_day = dates.hour
mask_wanted_hours = hour_of_day.isin([6])

n_samples_wanted_hours = mask_wanted_hours.sum()

dataset_wanted_hours = dataset.loc[mask_wanted_hours, :]
```

This should answer your question, I did not understand the other task-specific operations that you tried to achieve in your code example.